# How to fix this my error code program? I use Python 3.6

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, python-3.6

How to fix this error I use Python 3.6 and Database Oracle, I want to print data from databases, but shows errors, how can I fix it?

This is my databases:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKnzJ.png)

EMPLOYEESID(Primary Key), NIK(Unique Key)

This is My code:

```
#import oracle module
import cx_Oracle

#membuat koneksi ke database oracle dan sesuaikan settingannya
con= cx_Oracle.connect("db_employees/root@localhost:1521/xe")

#inisialisasi cursor object methodnya
cur= con.cursor()

#eksekusi query
cur.execute('select*from employees')

#mengambil data dari query
rows = cur.fetchall()

#print data
for row in rows:
    print('\nNIK    : '+row[0])
    print('Nama Karyawan    :   '+row[1])
    print('Jabatan  :   '+row[3])
    print('Birthdate    :   '+row[4])
    print('Address  :   '+row[5]+ '\n')

#close cursor object
cur.close()

#close connection
con.close()
```

This is My Message Errors:

```
   C:\Python36>python "D:\bisa.py"
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\bisa.py", line 18, in <module>
       print('\nNIK        : '+row[0])
   TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: The first thing I've seen is that it looks like you utilize the "cur" object instead of instantiating an object to store it. Ulfa, try removing rows = and let me know what that gives you

Comment: Try printing "row" and see what that gives you before trying to print the contents of the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use string formatting instead of concatenation as you can't add a string with a number. Change the following line

```
print('\nNIK        : '+row[0])
```

to

```
print('\nNIK        : {}'.format(row[0]))
```

Comment: this is work, but I get another problem, 
this is messages error:
C:\Python36>python "D:\bisa.py"
  File "D:\bisa.py", line 19
    print       ('Nama Karyawan :       '+row[1])
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

how can i fix it? sorry iam very much question because, i newbie

Comment: @UlfaHartina It could be because you have a syntax error in the line before. Could you check if the parentheses in the line 
`print('\nNIK        : {}'.format(row[0]))` 

have been set properly.